# How to do an infinite loop on a scrollView

Tags: android, uiscrollview

I want to implement a slot machine. My idea was to define three columns with three ScrollViews in my activity layout and inside of each scrollView I'm using a TableLayout with different ImageView. Then with a button I start a random scroll..

Sample code of one of my column/ScrollView:

```
<ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll_column_one"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/scroll_column_two"
        android:background="@color/lightgrey"
        android:scrollbars="none">

        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/table_slot_icon_column_one"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TableRow>

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/heart_c1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_heart" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow>

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/panda_c1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_panda" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow>

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/android_os_c1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_android_os" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow>

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/paypal_c1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_paypal" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow>

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/raspberry_c1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_raspberry" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow>

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/star_c1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_star" />
            </TableRow>

        </TableLayout>

    </ScrollView>
```

I would like to know if it's possible to do a loop when you are scrolling ? To be able to never stop the scolling action by reaching the bottom or the top of the ScrollView.

I've tried to detect with a custom class ObservableScrollView when the bottom is reached then go back to the top, but there is a kind of break on the UI between this two steps it's not very smooth.

```
        @Override
        public void onScrollEnded(ObservableScrollView scrollView, int x, int y, int oldx, int oldy) {
            scrollColumnOne.smoothScrollTo(0,0);
        }
```

It seems to be possible from what I can read with a listView but I really want to use a ScrollView and I don't want to use external lib at least for now.

Comment: Changing the code from ScrollView to a ListView is an option?

Comment: @jonathanrz as I said I know but I would like to know if it's possible to do that with a scrollView.

Comment: sorry, I didn't see the last line. IMHO it is not possible with a ScrollView, the only approach that I can imagine will be adding the same view twice and when reach the second one, remove the first and add it again to the bottom. A big rack, worst than using a LV/RV

Comment: ScrollView is for when the user is actually making a gesture to scroll the contents.  For a game like a slot machine, it would be be more appropriate to have a view that uses an animation to draw the images in a vertical motion.

Comment: I've used a listview and I can have my behaviour expected but now I have a problem to get 3 aligned lines at the same time for a slot machine: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33928815/slot-machine-with-endless-list-how-to-get-aligned-lines