# Slot machine with endless list how to get aligned lines

Tags: android, listview, scroll

I'm trying to implement a slot machin with 3 endless ListView. I wanted to do that with scroll view but I didn't find a solution to loop on a scrollView.

So basically I have three listview = 3 columns of my slot machine and when I click on button I want to scroll to a random position (a random integer between 0 (inclusive) and 300 (exclusive) which is my lists size) :

```
Random r = new Random();
int rPos1 = r.nextInt(300 - 0) +0;
int rPos2 = r.nextInt(300 - 0) + 0;
int rPos3 = r.nextInt(300 - 0) +0;

listSlotOne.smoothScrollToPosition(rPos1);
listSlotTwo.smoothScrollToPosition(rPos2);
listSlotThree.smoothScrollToPosition(rPos3);
```

So all this part is working but I can't manage to display each time as a result a clean result which mean three aligned lines on my screen ::

**Here a good result : three aligned lines**

[image]

**Here a bad result : lines are not aligned**

[image]

Is it possible to manage the behaviour of my random scroll to display every time a good result : **three aligned lines**.
I've noticed, for my 3 click on the play button I got a good result but after a fourth click I get a wrong result with not lines aligned and then it's random.

Answer (score 0):

If the smoothScrollToPosition() method doesn't snap, you are going to have to add your own snap meaning something like:

```
listSlotOne.smoothScrollToPosition((rPos1 % snap_height) * snap_height);
listSlotTwo.smoothScrollToPosition((rPos2 % snap_height) * snap_height);
listSlotThree.smoothScrollToPosition((rPos3 % snap_height) * snap_height);
```

or
    listSlotOne.smoothScrollToPosition((rPos1 / snap_height) * snap_height);
    listSlotTwo.smoothScrollToPosition((rPos2 / snap_height) * snap_height);
    listSlotThree.smoothScrollToPosition((rPos3 / snap_height) * snap_height);

I may be wrong, I'm not 100% sure but I believe that will solve your problem.

[Snap To Grid](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/67080/java-building-game-snap-to-grid)
I remember doing it with MOD though... well maybe this will help.

Cheers,

Demetry

Comment: I'm not really sure to understand how to get this snap_height you mean the height of the listview ? Thanks.

Comment: Well if its scrolling by pixel height you want the height of the object (each icon) to be your snap height.